# Antd TreeSelect issuing 'Warning: Same `value` exist in the tree: undefined'

Tags: reactjs, antd

My TreeSelect component issuing a `Warning: Same 'value' exist in the tree: undefined` warning but works correctly, what does that mean and how do I get rid of it?

```js
const treeData = {
    id: 1,
    title: '1',
    children: [{
        id: 2,
        title: '2',
        parent_id: '1'
    }]
}
//-------
<Form.Item
    label={label}
    name={name}
>
    <AntdTreeSelect
        treeDataSimpleMode
        treeData={treeData}
    />
</Form.Item>
```

I'm using antd 4.16.3

Answer (score 0):

Turns out when using `treeDataSimpleMode` prop, the TreeSelect expect a certain structure to the data, there should be a `pId` pointing to a parent id and the treeData prop should be a flat array the component itself will build the hierarchy from `id` and `pId`s, so changing the treeData to:

```js
const treeData = [{
    id: 1,
    title: '1'
},{
    id: 2,
    title: '2',
    pId: '1'
}]
```

will solve the problem; or alternatively you can give hints about your structure to the `treeDataSimpleMode` prop:

```js
<AntdTreeSelect
    treeDataSimpleMode={{pId: 'parent_id'}}
    treeData={treeData}
/>
```

**Note** this is only limited to `id` and `pid`, you have to have a `value` property in your data, but your data structure can be flat or tree, it works either way